# Pivoting count of column value using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have student data with id's and some values and I need to pivot the table for count of ID.

Here's an example of data:

```
    id     name  maths science  
0   B001   john   50     60
1   B021   Kenny  89     77
2   B041   Jessi  100    89
3   B121   Annie  91     73
4   B456   Mark   45     33
```

pivot table:

```
count of ID
5
```

Comment: You can directly get it without pivoting using `df.shape[0]` or if you want unique `id's` counr then `df.ID.nunique()`.

Comment: Yes @SandeepKadapa . But this i count value doesn't help me in upcoming steps . Need pivot table of particular column count. Based on this will be used as input for some other pivot table.

Comment: You should specify not only what you need, but also what you have tried and how that failed, otherwise it's not likely that you get a proper answer. Please invest some efforts to improve you post and ask an actual *question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of different ways to approach this, I would use either `shape` or `nunique()` as Sandeep suggested.

`data = {'id' : ['0','1','2','3','4'],
         'name' : ['john', 'kenny', 'jessi', 'Annie', 'Mark'],
         'math' : [50,89,100,91,45],
         'science' : [60,77,89,73,33]}`

`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

`print(df`)
`id name    math    science
0   0   john    50  60
1   1   kenny   89  77
2   2   jessi   100 89
3   3   Annie   91  73
4   4   Mark    45  33`

then pass either of the following:

`df.shape()` which gives you the length of a data frame.

or

```
in:df['id'].nunique()
out:5
```

Comment: Thank you. I can get the count of the Column in this method . But i need it as pivot table. In excel if we pivot this table we will get it count of particular column. Like as i need it here. [ select the ID column (up to the last row) and insert a Pivot Table. Drag the ID field under Row label, and drag the Status field again under Values as well (you'll get Count of ID). ]  i need same result in python as well.